# pyCURL SSL download: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Tags: python, django, pycurl

I am lost for few hours on this little issue.

I need to download XML from page with auth by login and pass.

```
def load(URL = 'https://xxx/'):

   URL +=  'data.xml?'
   URL += 'detail=custom:id,name' 
   URL += '&limit=0' 

   import cStringIO
   buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

   curl = pycurl.Curl()
   curl.setopt(curl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % ('Login', 'Pass'))
   curl.setopt(curl.URL, URL)
   curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)

   curl.perform()

   data = str(buf.getvalue())
```

It works fine if run server on local host (win 8, django 1.6.1., python 2.7, manage.py runserver)

When I deployed page on server, it throws this error:

```
(35, 'error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error')
```

Server:

2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64

Bitnami djangostack 1.5.5-2

pycurl-7.19.3.1

Can anybody please help how to fix? Or help me with another way how to download xml from SSL page?
Thx for any help ;)

Comment: Try something like `curl.setopt(curl.CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3)` before the `perform` call?

Comment: It seems pycurl doesn't has something like this :( I tried: curl.setopt(curl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0) 
curl.setopt(curl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False) It doesn't work,...

Comment: import urllib2, base64

    request = urllib2.Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (login, pass)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
    data = urllib2.urlopen(request) lead to this <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error>

Comment: related: [Tomcat 7 and curl – SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error](http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2012/02/19/tomcat-7-and-curl-ssl23_get_server_hellotlsv1-alert-internal-error/).

Comment: @PasikCz: don't put relevant for the question info in the comments. [Update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22275549/edit)

Comment: try to specify sslv3 or tlsv1 protocol explicitly and restrict ciphers.